# Need to extract data from string by regexp_substr

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

I have a `["1101124","1101123","123456"]`, I need to get the end result as rows for the numbers which are in the bracket.
How can I achieve this by using regular expression in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expression to try to parse JSON data; use a proper JSON parser:

```sql
SELECT value
FROM   JSON_TABLE(
         '["1101124","1101123","123456"]',
         '$[*]'
         COLUMNS(
           value VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$'
         )
       )
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 1101124 |
> | 1101123 |
> | 123456 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=02669ad7edae0a8b11c001dfffd46782)*

Answer (score 0):

If `["1101124","1101123","123456"]` is a string:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT '["1101124","1101123","123456"]' str FROM dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT trim(regexp_substr(str, '[0-9]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
  5  FROM DATA
  6  CONNECT BY regexp_substr(str , '[0-9]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
  7  /

STR
----------------------------------------
1101124
1101123
123456

3 rows selected.

SQL>
```